# How do I pull a random line from a CSV file and assign to a class? Python3

Tags: python, python-3.3

I'm currently struggling with file IO in python and assigning to a class. I have a csv file with multiple lines, and I need to randomly select one of those lines and assign it to a class I have already defined. For example:

csv file:

```
weapon.csv
sword1,5,1,sharp
sword2,10,2,very sharp

class Weapon:
    def __init__ (self, name, value, weight, description):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.weight = weight
        self.description = description
```

From this I would like to end up with a weapon with the values in the row in the csv to match the way they are written in the init section, so if row 1 was randomly selected from the csv, Weapon.name = sword1, Weapon.value = 5, Weapon.weight = 1, Weapon.description = sharp

Any help on how to do this would be great as I'm struggling to understand file I/O in python. Thanks!

Comment: why do you want to select them randomly? Also I think you mean to assign the values to an instance of Weapon right?

Comment: Basically the program is a random loot generator. If a weapon is generated, I need a line to be selected from the csv and assigned to the Weapon class. The weapon does not need to be instanced, as I'm happy for it to be overwritten once it's printed and the next item is generated, which may or may not be another weapon. The random selection from the CSV is integral to the generator pumping out different weapons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import random
import csv

class Weapon: 
    def __init__ (self, name, value, weight, description):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.weight = weight
        self.description = description      

with open('weapon.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
  weaponscsv = list(csv.reader(csvfile))    

lengthofcsv = len(weaponscsv)
position = random.randrange(0, lengthofcsv)

aweapon = Weapon(*weaponscsv[position])

print aweapon.name
print aweapon.value
print aweapon.weight
print aweapon.description
```

Comment: Perfect! This does exactly what I want it to do, all I had to do was add brackets around the things to print to comply with python 3 and it works! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should save text values in a csv surrounded in quotes.  This will allow you to use eval to process each int, str, etc.

csv file: 
    "sword1",5,1,"sharp" 
    "sword2",10,2,"very sharp"

Assuming there are N (predetermined) lines in weapons.csv

```
from random import randint

rand_index = randint(0, N - 1)

with open('weapon.csv') as f:
    for j, row in enumerate(f):
        if j == i:
            my_row = row.split(',')
processed_row = [eval(x) for x in my_row]
weapon = Weapon(*processed_row)
```

You would be much better off keeping the weapons loaded in memory as the cost of reading the file over and over would be expensive.  A better approach would be

```
from random import sample

def get_random_weapon(L):
    row = sample(L, 1)
    return Weapon(*row)

with open('weapon.csv') as f:
    weapon_list = [[eval(x) for x in row.split(',')] for row in f]

weapon = get_random_weapon(weapon_list)
```